# Two stations written with the same kanji but pronounced differently — why?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, names

The [JR Nara line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nara_Line_(JR_West)) and the [Keihan Uji line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keihan_Uji_Line) are almost parallel on their way through southeastern Kyoto and Uji. In most areas, both have a station and the names are clearly related if not identical (e.g. both have Rokujizou and Oubaku; JR has Momoyama while Keihan has Momoyama-Minamiguchi etc.).

However, there is also a rather interesting pair of stations between Oubaku and Rokujizou: both stations are written 木幡 in kanji yet Keihan gives the pronunciation as [こわた](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kowata_Station) while JR gives the pronunciation as [こはた](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohata_Station). This matches what is heard in the announcements on their respective trains.

I assume that the name corresponds to the name of the surrounding part of Uji. Unfortunately, I don’t know which of the two pronunciations would be correct for that suburb. But how is it possible that the same combination of kanji when used as a name for the same place gives two different pronunciations?

[A map showing both stations in Uji.](https://osm.org/go/7QHGR1WC9-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Historically, は and わ are very closely related sounds. Before the spelling reforms around the end of World War II, the kana は was commonly pronounced in both ways (and of course this survives into modern Japanese in the form of the particle は).

So this is probably a case where the place name was historically こはた but the pronunciation of the は was never fully standardized, and the two different versions still survive in different contexts today.

Incidentally, the Japanese Wikipedia entries for the two stations include a note that in addition to こ**は**た and こ**わ**た, there are some nearby placenames that use the same kanji pronounced こ**ば**た (rendaku of course being another case of a common sound change that's not always consistently applied). What a very inconsistently pronounced word!